# How to use for loop to find all instances of a substring in a string

Tags: python, list, loops

For a school project, I have to find the positions of all instances of list elements within a string. I am inexperienced with Python and may simply not understand how to do this with limited knowledge about if statements, loops, variables, and lists.

The only method I have attempted so far is using a for loop. I created counter variable "i", and for every list[i] in the string, I need its position. Before I can start finding positions, I need to identify the list elements in the string.

```
list1=['a','b','c']
str1='aabfh'
i=0
while "some condition":
    for list1[i] in str1:
        print(list1[i])
    i=i+1
```

I expected an output like:

```
a
a
b
```

but instead got:

```
a
a
b
f
h
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You don't get what you say that you get. Your program instead crashes with a run-time error. Your loops make little sense. This looks like a homework problem in which you were supposed to *replace* `"some condition"` with an actual condition, not leave it as a literal string.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that each string in the list1 list is a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the for loop wrong.

This takes each character in the string, assigns it to x, and prints it:

```
for x in 'aabfh':
    print (x)
```

This takes each character in the string, assigns it to list1[i], and prints it:

```
for list1[i] in 'aabfh':
    print(list1[i])
```

In your code, if you look at list1, you will find that it has been changed to ['h', 'h', 'h'] because that's what you told it to do (or at least as many h's as "some condition" will allow).

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop raise `NameError`. you can't access to elements of a list in for loop like that. change it to this one to print your desired output:

```
for char in str1:
    if char in list1:
        print(char)

a
a
b
```

for printing its position you can use `index`:

```
for char in str1:
    if char in list1:
        print(list1.index(char))

0
0
1
```

Comment: You could also do something like `for char, i in enumerate(str1):` and then `print(char + " " + str(i))` as your example would only print out the first location it's found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

As @Kenny Ostrom pointed out in his answer, your `for` format is wrong.

The format of a `for` loop is:

```
for new_variable_name in list:
    print(new_variable_name)
```

`new_variable_name` is assigned to each item in that list

`for` loops iterate over each item in a list once. In your case

```
for char in str1
    print(char)
```

Would print

```
a
a
b
f
h
```

Another issue you're running into is an unnecessary `while` loop. You are surrounding your `for` loop in a `while` loop that will keep running and not stop. If you didn't have a `for` loop, this might be useful to you, but it's unnecessary because you're already using a `for` loop.

The structure of your program should look something like this if you want to use a for loop:

```
list1=['a','b','c']
str1='aabfh'
i=0
for character in str1:
   '''
   Some code here that figures out **if** the character is in list1 and then prints that character. 
   '''
```

You should be able to figure this out from here.

Comment: I didn't want to give too much info on the actual solution. homework. But it seems tailor made to use a specific builtin which is handy for indexes while iterating over a list.

Comment: That is true. There is a way to do this with list indexes as well. I see your point about there being a `while <condition>`, but with the rest of the code there really isn't an easy way to tell what <condition> is because there's already a for loop.